# How to redefine \max?

Tags: math-operators, sans-serif

I want to redefine `\max`.

The original definition gives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\max_{i\in I} a_i\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

My new definition is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\max\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\max}{\mathsf{max}}

\begin{document}
\[\max_{i\in I} a_i\]
\end{document}
```

But the output is not as expected, with the `$i\in I$` part not below the `\max` part.

[image]

How can I change the font of `\max` without having this issue.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator*` (with star).

Comment: LaTeX is a totally absurd language (and I love it)